# How to view the processed SelectCommand of Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-ajax

I have a most basic out-of-the-box implementation of a Telerik `RadAutoCompleteBox`. I would like to inspect the processed `SelectCommand` generated by the component using the debugger, prior to that command getting sent to the SQL server - so that I can see the actual SQL being generated.

I tried to use the [`OnDataSourceSelect`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox-ondatasourceselect.html) event so that I could inspect `AutoCompleteBoxDataSourceSelectEventArgs` at runtime, however, it appears that if this event is used the component assumes that the developer wants to provide custom server-side filtering of the data and therefore the `SelectCommand` never gets processed.

Comment: So, what's the question? If you need details about the innards of the code, download the source from your account, open the project, add it to your solution, reference it and start it in debug mode. You can step through the code at your leisure then.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know the source code was available!!! If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need details about the innards of the code, download the source from your account, open the project, add it to your solution, reference it and start it in debug mode. You can step through the code at your leisure then.